# Problema con bucle en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Soy Nuevo Programando en JavaScript y estoy intentando creando una Billetera Virtual.

Mi problema es el siguiente: Como dije arriba, estoy tratando de crear una billetera Virtual para un proyecto de un curso que estoy haciendo y a la hora de hacer el código de interacción con el usuario no me corta o no me sale del bucle. Soy consiente que esta todo metido en el mismo bucle pero no estoy pudiendo separarlo sin que se rompa.

El código como esta me funciona perfecto solo que cuando le doy a la opción 5 (la opción 5 es para salir del programa) en el menú de interacción me da el saludo que tiene pre inscripto "Muchas Gracias" pero no sale, sigue corriendo el código indicándome alertar que están después del `Switch`, mi código es el siguiente.

```
let intentos = 3;
let saldoActual;
let opcion;
let usuario = prompt("Cree su nombre de usuario");
let contraseña = prompt("Cree su contraseña");

// Loggin
class Cliente {
    constructor(usuario, contraseña) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.contraseña = Number(contraseña);
    }
}
const persona = new Cliente(usuario, contraseña)


// Generamos un For tradiconal
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let user = prompt("Ingrese su usuario");
    let pass = Number(prompt("Ingrese su contraseña"));

    // Si coloca otro dato que no sean los pedido les saldra el siguien mensaje
    if (!user || !pass) {
        alert("ingresa los datos solicitados");

    } else {

        // Si los datos ingresados Coinciden con los datos pedidos le damos la Bienvenida
        if (user == persona.usuario && pass == persona.contraseña) {

            alert("Bienvenido " + persona.usuario);

            // Le pedimos al usuario que coloque el saldo actual que posee 
            saldoActual = Number(prompt("Ingrese el Saldo Actual"));
            alert("Bienvenido al Menu Principal");

            // Creamos el Menu para hacer las operaciones
            do {
                opcion = Number(prompt("Que operacion desea realizar: \n1.Consultar el saldo en la cuenta \n"
                    + "2.Depositar dinero\n"
                    + "3.Extraer dinero\n"
                    + "4.Consultar Datos de la Cuenta\n"
                    + "5.Salir"));

                switch (opcion) {
                    case 1:
                        consultarSaldo();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ingresarDinero();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        retiroDinero();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        consultarDatos();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        alert("Muchas Gracias")
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("Ingrese una opcion correcta")
                }
            } while (opcion != 6);
        }
        alert("Usuario y/o Contraseña incorrecto. Te quedan " + intentos + " intentos");
    }
    intentos--;
}
if (intentos <= 0) { alert("Usuario Bloqueado"); }



// Ingresar Dinero a la Cuenta
function ingresarDinero() {
    let ingreso = Number(prompt("Ingrese la cantidad de desee depositar "));
    saldoActual = (saldoActual + ingreso);
    alert("Ingresó $" + ingreso);
}

// Retirar Dinero de la Cuenta
function retiroDinero() {
    let retiro = Number(prompt("Ingrese el monto que desee extraer"));
    if (retiro <= saldoActual) {
        saldoActual = (saldoActual - retiro);
        alert("Extrajo: $" + retiro);

    } else {
        alert("Su saldo es insuficiente");
    }
}

//  Consulta Datos
function consultarDatos() {
    alert("Su Nombre de Usuario es: " + persona.usuario);
    alert("Su Contraseña es: " + persona.contraseña);
}

// Consultar Saldo
function consultarSaldo() {
    alert("Su Saldo Actual es de: $" + saldoActual);
}
```

Comment: Y si colocas `while (opcion != 5)` y no `while (opcion != 6);`

Comment: Esta puesto asi, lo intente asi --> while (opcion != 5) <-- pero tampoco

Comment: la variable intentos agregala al codigo por fa, no esta

Comment: ahi coloque todas las variables y funciones, ahora lo pueden  ejecutar?

Comment: Dónde declaras la variable `persona`? intente ejecutar el snippet de tu código pero falta esa variable

Comment: esa variable es la ultima que me faltaba, perdona andres

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te dejo el código llegue tarde, lo estaba editando. Fijate que te modifique arriba el nombre de usuario y contraseña para poder ingresar (volverlo a cambiar).
Tu error era en la condición del While del final tenes que preguntar si es distinto a la opción 5. Y también te faltaba colocar el Break para salir definitivamente.

```js
let intentos = 3;
let saldoActual;
let opcion;
let usuario = "Guille";
let contraseña = 123;

// Ingresar Dinero a la Cuenta
function ingresarDinero() {
    let ingreso = Number(prompt("Ingrese la cantidad de desee depositar "));
    saldoActual = (saldoActual + ingreso);
    alert("Ingresó $" + ingreso);
}

// Retirar Dinero de la Cuenta
function retiroDinero() {
    let retiro = Number(prompt("Ingrese el monto que desee extraer"));
    if (retiro <= saldoActual) {
        saldoActual = (saldoActual - retiro);
        alert("Extrajo: $" + retiro);

    } else {
        alert("Su saldo es insuficiente");
    }
}

//  Consulta Datos
function consultarDatos() {
    alert("Su Nombre de Usuario es: " + persona.usuario);
    alert("Su Contraseña es: " + persona.contraseña);
}

// Consultar Saldo
function consultarSaldo() {
    alert("Su Saldo Actual es de: $" + saldoActual);
}

// Generamos un For tradiconal
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let user = prompt("Ingrese su usuario");
    let pass = Number(prompt("Ingrese su contraseña"));

    // Si coloca otro dato que no sean los pedido les saldra el siguien mensaje
    if (!user || !pass) {
        alert("ingresa los datos solicitados");

    } else {

        // Si los datos ingresados Coinciden con los datos pedidos le damos la Bienvenida
        if (user == usuario && pass == contraseña) {

            alert("Bienvenido " + user);

            // Le pedimos al usuario que coloque el saldo actual que posee 
            saldoActual = Number(prompt("Ingrese el Saldo Actual"));
            alert("Bienvenido al Menu Principal");

            // Creamos el Menu para hacer las operaciones
            do {
                opcion = Number(prompt("Que operacion desea realizar: \n1.Consultar el saldo en la cuenta \n"
                    + "2.Depositar dinero\n"
                    + "3.Extraer dinero\n"
                    + "4.Consultar Datos de la Cuenta\n"
                    + "5.Salir"));

                switch (opcion) {
                    case 1:
                        consultarSaldo();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ingresarDinero();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        retiroDinero();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        consultarDatos();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        alert("Muchas Gracias")
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("Ingrese una opcion correcta")
                }
            } while (opcion != 5);
            break;
            
        } else {
            alert("Usuario y/o Contraseña incorrecto. Te quedan " + intentos + " intentos");
            intentos--;
        }
    }
}
if (intentos <= 0) { alert("Usuario Bloqueado"); }
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias Guille por tomarte el tiempo!!

Answer (score 1):

Mi solución lo hice antes de que editaras la pregunta pero solo borre las declaraciones de las funciones y eso ya que el error no tenia que ver con eso.

Hice un objeto `persona` pero era no más para la demostración ya que no sabía cómo lo tenías declarado.
Para la próxima pon en tu pregunta todo obsolutamente todo.

```
const persona = {
  usuario: "user",
  contraseña: "12345"
}
let intentos = 2
// Generamos un For tradiconal
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let user = prompt("Ingrese su usuario");
    let pass = Number(prompt("Ingrese su contraseña"));
  
    // Si coloca otro dato que no sean los pedido les saldra el siguien mensaje
    if (!user || !pass) {
        alert("ingresa los datos solicitados");
        
    } else if (user != persona.usuario && pass != persona.contraseña){
      //else if para validar que los datos sean correctos y de una vez manda todos los mensajes necesarios
      alert("datos incorrectos")
      intentos--;
      alert("Usuario y/o Contraseña incorrecto. Te quedan " + intentos + " intentos");
    }else {
  
        // Si los datos ingresados Coinciden con los datos pedidos le damos la Bienvenida
        if (user == persona.usuario && pass == persona.contraseña) {
  
            alert("Bienvenido " + persona.usuario);
  
            // Le pedimos al usuario que coloque el saldo actual que posee 
            saldoActual = Number(prompt("Ingrese el Saldo Actual"));
            alert("Bienvenido al Menu Principal");
  
            // Creamos el Menu para hacer las operaciones
            do {
                opcion = Number(prompt("Que operacion desea realizar: \n1.Consultar el saldo en la cuenta \n"
                    + "2.Depositar dinero\n"
                    + "3.Extraer dinero\n"
                    + "4.Consultar Datos de la Cuenta\n"
                    + "5.Salir"));
  
                switch (opcion) {
                    case 1:
                        console.log("Saldo actual")
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        console.log("Ingreso dinero")
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        console.log("Retiro dinero")
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        console.log("Consultar datos")
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        alert("Muchas Gracias")
                        
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("Ingrese una opcion correcta")
                }
            } while (opcion != 5);//sale del do while cuando la opción es 5 y abajo inmediatamente con el break termina la ejecución.
            break; //Para salir por completo y no volver al loop de "introduzca usuario..."
        }    
    }
    if (intentos <= 0) { alert("Usuario Bloqueado"); break }//break que saca de ejecucion el programa cuando los intentos sean 0 e impide el loop
  }
```

Cualquier inconveniente agregas un comentario para saber si fallo algo.

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias Jose por la ayuda, te lo agraste un monton!! Ahora me pongo con eso

Comment: Bueno, si no es mucho pedir marca la respuesta como aceptada por fa.